# gcp terraform - how to add pubsub_topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am quite new to GCP and terraform.
I am trying to create pubsub_topic with terraform in Google Cloud and link it with budget, so budget will use the topic as a link with cloud function (passing notifications).

I am stuck at creating the topic.

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "topic" {
  name    = alert_topic
  project = my_project
}

resource "google_billing_budget" "global-budget" {
  provider        = google-beta
  billing_account = var.billing_account_id
  display_name    = "Global Billing Budget"

  amount {
    specified_amount {
      currency_code = "EUR"
      units         = "500"
    }
  }

  threshold_rules {
    threshold_percent = 0.5
  }

  all_updates_rule {
    pubsub_topic = projects / my_project / topics / alert_topic
  }
}
```

`terraform plan` command results:

```
A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one
attribute access, specifying the resource name.
```

What I do wrong?

```
terraform version
Terraform v0.12.23
+ provider.google v3.13.0
+ provider.google-beta v3.13.0
```

Comment: What does the full error show? You seem to have cut out some of the surrounding context to the error.

Comment: I added quotes on the resources...so the problem is gone. silly.

Answer (score 2):

pubsub_topic required quotes

```
all_updates_rule {
    pubsub_topic = "projects/my_project/topics/alert_topic"
  }
```